# Separation of variables and why integration of 1/x terms gives ln|x|

Tags: integration

So assuming I got something like 
$$x'(u)=-\frac{x}{u}$$
which gives me then (with separation of variables)
$$\int\frac{dx}{x}=\int{-\frac{du}{u}}$$
So my question is: Why do I get
$$ln|x|=-ln(u)+c, c \in \mathbb{R} $$
instead of
$$ln(x)=-ln(u)+c, c \in \mathbb{R}  $$
?

Comment: Does the natural logarithim of a non-positive number exist?

Comment: @Avraham it does not but that would mean I'd need  ln|u| as well since I do not know whether u is positive or negative

Comment: furthermore I feel like it's wrong to wrap it to make x a absolute value since you said it yourself that the logarithm does not exist for negative values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $|x| \ge 0$ for all $x$, $\ln|x|$ is defined for all $x\neq 0$. It has derivative $\frac{1}{x}$ for all $x\neq 0$, so $\int \frac{1}{x}\, dx = \ln|x| + C$.